# Changing the font for a custom environment

Tags: fonts, macros, formatting, environments

I can't figure out how to embed a command like `\textbf` or something in a newly created environment, I have:

```
\newenvironment{definition}
  {\begin{quote}}
  {\end{quote}}
```

I want to customize my definition environment with some additional commands, but if I try something simple like:

```
\newenvironment{definition}
  {\textbf{\begin{quote}}
  {\end{quote}}}
```

`pdflatex` refuses to compile a PDF. Where am I wrong? Is there a limit for a newly created environment?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a declaration instead:

```
\newenvironment{definition}
  {\bfseries\begin{quote}}
  {\end{quote}}
```

Declarations are like switches, their effect ends when the environment is closed.

Comment: thanks, just to know, where i can find the complete reference to this basic commands for latex?

Comment: @Micro: In *LaTeX: A Document Preparation System* by Leslie Lamport, the creator of LaTeX. For freely available online sources, have a look at [Introductions and Guides to LaTeX](http://texblog.net/latex-link-archive/introduction-guide/). There should be links on this site as well.